# Stack Exchange API is returning boolean(false) For 'is_answered' On Question With Accepted Answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2

When you view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466804/convert-flat-text-file-to-pdf) question you see a closed question which has an accepted answer.

When you get the API info for it you get this:

```
["question_id"]=>
int(17466804)
["creation_date"]=>
int(1372930412)
["score"]=>
int(-4)
["closed_date"]=>
int(1372932196)
["title"]=>
string(29) "convert flat text file to pdf"
["closed_reason"]=>
string(9) "off-topic"
["link"]=>
string(73) "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466804/convert-flat-text-file-to-pdf"
["is_answered"]=>
bool(false)
["close_vote_count"]=>
int(0)
["reopen_vote_count"]=>
int(0)
["delete_vote_count"]=>
int(0)
```

The field `is_answered` is returning `false` even though the question has not only an answer, but an accepted one.

I thought it might have to do with the question being closed. However, other closed questions which also have an accepted answer correctly return `true`. For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465535/how-can-i-get-all-substrings-matching-a-regex-from-another-string-in-r) question.

The other reason could be the negative score for the answer. But it should not effect the field since even a negative score answer can end up being correct. If this is intended behavior it should be documented on the [question](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) doc page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Per [Kevin Montrose's answer](https://stackapps.com/a/4231/7653) and its comments:

The bug has now been fixed and [the `is_answered` property](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) will return true if *either* of these is true:

- The question has an accepted answer
- The question has an answer with a score > 0

To detect just whether a question has an accepted answer, merely check that [the `accepted_answer_id` property](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) is present and has an integer value

---

---

This looks like a bug rather than (just) a documentation error.  The `is_answered` property should mirror the `hasaccepted` search key. (See *Advanced Search Tips* on [the Search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search).)

If we [search for `hasaccepted:yes`, the question shows up](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpdf%5D%20hasaccepted:yes%20title:%22convert%20flat%20text%20file%20to%20pdf%22).
Screenshot in case the Q is deleted ([Click for larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IFQU.gif)) :
[image: Search results]

[**The Help Center**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) makes no mentions that answers don't count if they have negative scores.

Likewise, [I could find nothing on Meta (so far) that says that some "answered" questions don't count as answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%20answer%20negative).

Note that [the API returns `is_answered` is false, but the question also has an `accepted_answer_id`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=17466804&filter=!%29-FeHpKSPlKPMRQQ&site=stackoverflow&run=true). So that seems like a contradiction right there.

Also, [the API's `/search/advanced` path, with `accepted=True` returns the question, as expected](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&tagged=php&title=convert%20flat%20text%20file%20to%20pdf&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Answer (score 4):

Tricky.

This was a consequence of the API misinterpreting a normalized field used elsewhere in the system to indicate whether or not a post has *upvoted answers*.

Everywhere else, "is answered" is true if either of the following are met:

- The question has an accepted answer
- The question has an answer with a score > 0

The API wasn't doing the "or" check.

This was fixed in the last deploy.

Comment: So, to be clear, to mimic the useful `hasaccepted` search, we must check the API results to see if the `accepted_answer_id` property is present.?.     The `is_answered` property is now = `({has accepted ans} OR {has upvoted ans})`.?.  Also **is it *upvoted* answer or answer *with a positive score*?**

Comment: @BrockAdams with a score > 0 ; `is_answered` should be set if either there is an accepted answer, or their is a > 0 score answer.  `hasaccepted` is just checking `accepted_answer_id`.