# wrong results of api /search/advanced

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, search

I am querying for results of [/search/advanced](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search). The request I am sending is

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?key=`key`&access_token=`access_token`&site=stackoverflow.com&page=1&pagesize=20&order=desc&sort=relevance&q=signalr&filter=!tRhd)yG5RfdF0fv8E-NwvlZNrfzIwPf
```

The question as marked in this snapshot[image]  is present in the json result with one rank below and the question with lesser rank is coming above.

Also, question titled `SignalR - StartUp` has `is_answered = true` even when there is no accepted answer. Another question `signalR undefined` has `is_answered = false` which has same conditions, i.e., no accepted answer. Here the first case is giving wrong results.

Kindly give `access_token` and `key` in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

`is_answered` is `true` if there is at least one positively scoring answer. It doesn't actually mean 'marked as accepted'. See more about how it works [in this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/4231/26088)

Also,

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?site=stackoverflow.com&page=1&pagesize=20&order=desc&sort=relevance&q=signalr
```

(URL without filter so I don't need key/access token)

gives the JSON:

```
{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":7276,
            "user_id":960567,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":79,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d95e231d783a218eba22a6bd04652255?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"user960567",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/960567/user960567"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":20473,
         "accepted_answer_id":7874352,
         "answer_count":3,
         "score":115,
         "last_activity_date":1439886702,
         "creation_date":1318940205,
         "question_id":7807066,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807066/how-signalr-works-internally",
         "title":"How SignalR works internally?"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":7096,
            "user_id":97382,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":68,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b154c4e4a979b7201ad47881520a08af?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"Craig W.",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/97382/craig-w"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":26263,
         "accepted_answer_id":9281143,
         "answer_count":5,
         "score":104,
         "last_activity_date":1452610249,
         "creation_date":1329236849,
         "question_id":9280484,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280484/signalr-why-choose-hub-vs-persistent-connection",
         "title":"SignalR: Why choose Hub vs. Persistent Connection?"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "c#",
            "asp.net",
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":4417,
            "user_id":449907,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":74,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b2ea20cc07619dd7cdc286f09e2ecca3?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"Rocky Singh",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/449907/rocky-singh"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":23205,
         "accepted_answer_id":8942623,
         "answer_count":14,
         "score":32,
         "last_activity_date":1456907475,
         "creation_date":1327063045,
         "question_id":8941595,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941595/signalr-signalr-hubs-giving-404-error",
         "title":"SignalR &quot;signalr/hubs&quot; giving 404 error"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "jquery",
            "asp.net-mvc-3",
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":1872,
            "user_id":610168,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":56,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/620e1401766b11cd74f9a503fb953ed6?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"bdparrish",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/610168/bdparrish"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":8259,
         "answer_count":5,
         "score":13,
         "last_activity_date":1349459751,
         "creation_date":1326942995,
         "question_id":8920621,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920621/signalr-startup",
         "title":"SignalR - StartUp"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":162,
            "user_id":1447975,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":50,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7ecb2a888caf6ef8b5fbdce03d725f92?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"CBaker",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/1447975/cbaker"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":40,
         "accepted_answer_id":35758152,
         "answer_count":1,
         "score":0,
         "last_activity_date":1457012195,
         "creation_date":1456952929,
         "question_id":35758082,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758082/signalr-the-signalr-hubs-file",
         "title":"SignalR - The signalr/hubs file"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "requirejs",
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":38,
            "user_id":327911,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4063cd31f7de485431927b28f82828c0?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"coreyperkins",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/327911/coreyperkins"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":2833,
         "accepted_answer_id":11479051,
         "answer_count":2,
         "score":5,
         "last_activity_date":1405005809,
         "creation_date":1342216920,
         "last_edit_date":1342323312,
         "question_id":11478946,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478946/require-js-signalr",
         "title":"Require.js + SignalR"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "asp.net",
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":44,
            "user_id":1847005,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/13a791640ad72effea4ed5e545ad8a61?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"whebz",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/1847005/whebz"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":393,
         "accepted_answer_id":14099327,
         "answer_count":2,
         "score":5,
         "last_activity_date":1356942551,
         "creation_date":1356010717,
         "last_edit_date":1356014159,
         "question_id":13973425,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973425/signalr-methodaccessexception",
         "title":"SignalR MethodAccessException"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "c#",
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":83,
            "user_id":2151460,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/594ab11fd7c482dbdc5c7d854de4fff0?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"Dexception",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/2151460/dexception"
         },
         "is_answered":false,
         "view_count":198,
         "answer_count":0,
         "score":1,
         "last_activity_date":1436399925,
         "creation_date":1436399925,
         "question_id":31305882,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305882/signalr-err-conection-refused-on-signalr-hubs",
         "title":"SignalR ERR_CONECTION_REFUSED on signalr/hubs"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":10345,
            "user_id":166303,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":75,
            "profile_image":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/29eUl.jpg?s=128&g=1",
            "display_name":"reach4thelasers",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/166303/reach4thelasers"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":5296,
         "accepted_answer_id":9995081,
         "answer_count":3,
         "score":24,
         "last_activity_date":1372554893,
         "creation_date":1333447281,
         "question_id":9991035,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991035/securing-signalr-calls",
         "title":"Securing SignalR Calls"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "timer",
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":1783,
            "user_id":645924,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":78,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2bcc518c6f92a560dc32647190319ace?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"Ryan",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/645924/ryan"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":481,
         "answer_count":1,
         "score":1,
         "last_activity_date":1342565236,
         "creation_date":1342002034,
         "question_id":11430517,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430517/signalr-overhead",
         "title":"signalR overhead"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "c#",
            "asp.net",
            "asp.net-mvc",
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":8,
            "user_id":899974,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/77be3b28cd3567ffa632d75aba0a2090?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"ishahrier",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/899974/ishahrier"
         },
         "is_answered":false,
         "view_count":397,
         "answer_count":0,
         "score":1,
         "last_activity_date":1414669608,
         "creation_date":1404240425,
         "last_edit_date":1414669608,
         "question_id":24517253,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517253/signalr-authentication",
         "title":"SignalR authentication"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "javascript",
            "signalr",
            "signalr-hub"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":10,
            "user_id":1576800,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":50,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d60ba6a7b217f636f7bcace4ed116446?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"Stuart Armstrong",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/1576800/stuart-armstrong"
         },
         "is_answered":false,
         "view_count":625,
         "answer_count":1,
         "score":1,
         "last_activity_date":1345537730,
         "creation_date":1344131433,
         "last_edit_date":1344132031,
         "question_id":11813373,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813373/signalr-undefined",
         "title":"signalR undefined"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "signalr",
            "high-load"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":105,
            "user_id":3106031,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":50,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/70134c59b75fae8967d97bb2769ce85b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"Viet NT",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/3106031/viet-nt"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":2040,
         "answer_count":1,
         "score":3,
         "last_activity_date":1407327358,
         "creation_date":1407326548,
         "question_id":25159905,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159905/signalr-performance",
         "title":"SignalR performance"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "c#",
            "asp.net-mvc",
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":8637,
            "user_id":1477388,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":91,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/260bb71d267800168d25e7c3be88b1c5?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"user1477388",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/1477388/user1477388"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":1270,
         "accepted_answer_id":22918490,
         "answer_count":1,
         "score":7,
         "last_activity_date":1396889530,
         "creation_date":1396887314,
         "question_id":22917723,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917723/signalr-security",
         "title":"SignalR Security"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "signalr",
            "signalr-hub"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":3951,
            "user_id":17194,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":90,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b0e76ddb571766c264d3a4bdff71c27f?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"ChrisCa",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/17194/chrisca"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":1376,
         "accepted_answer_id":11950505,
         "answer_count":2,
         "score":2,
         "last_activity_date":1344940607,
         "creation_date":1344502812,
         "last_edit_date":1344512940,
         "question_id":11879927,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879927/signalr-disconections",
         "title":"SignalR Disconections"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "c#",
            "asp.net",
            "node.js",
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":885,
            "user_id":3676005,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":96,
            "profile_image":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/viEMs.png?s=128&g=1",
            "display_name":"acostela",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/3676005/acostela"
         },
         "is_answered":false,
         "view_count":84,
         "answer_count":0,
         "score":0,
         "last_activity_date":1450100534,
         "creation_date":1450100534,
         "question_id":34268530,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268530/signalr-nodejs",
         "title":"SignalR + nodeJS"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "c#",
            "json",
            "json.net",
            "signalr",
            ".net-4.5"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":15149,
            "user_id":144746,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":95,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/170e317e1e3d42b520786bcec9dfb409?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"Voo",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/144746/voo"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":287,
         "accepted_answer_id":32404249,
         "answer_count":1,
         "score":5,
         "last_activity_date":1441670352,
         "creation_date":1441034515,
         "last_edit_date":1441094888,
         "question_id":32314638,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314638/signalr-typenamehandling",
         "title":"SignalR Typenamehandling"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "asp.net",
            "iis",
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":543,
            "user_id":685590,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":86,
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8bfc28769485f5a754c4415ae146d7b3?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "display_name":"user685590",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/685590/user685590"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":14257,
         "accepted_answer_id":11187447,
         "answer_count":8,
         "score":24,
         "last_activity_date":1431685061,
         "creation_date":1340363423,
         "last_edit_date":1370488030,
         "question_id":11155064,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155064/signalr-signalr-hubs-404-not-found",
         "title":"SignalR /signalr/hubs 404 Not Found"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "javascript",
            "asp.net",
            "angularjs",
            "signalr"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":36,
            "user_id":5731750,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f9854c745e4162a7e093362fcdeebb73?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
            "display_name":"wroe12",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/5731750/wroe12"
         },
         "is_answered":false,
         "view_count":33,
         "answer_count":0,
         "score":0,
         "last_activity_date":1455992331,
         "creation_date":1455992331,
         "question_id":35527177,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527177/signalr-asp-net",
         "title":"SignalR ASP.NET"
      },
      {  
         "tags":[  
            "c#",
            "signalr",
            "amazon-elasticache"
         ],
         "owner":{  
            "reputation":972,
            "user_id":636160,
            "user_type":"registered",
            "accept_rate":23,
            "profile_image":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR6nl.jpg?s=128&g=1",
            "display_name":"Andy",
            "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/636160/andy"
         },
         "is_answered":true,
         "view_count":737,
         "answer_count":1,
         "score":47,
         "last_activity_date":1456237640,
         "creation_date":1435254722,
         "last_edit_date":1448438993,
         "question_id":31057333,
         "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057333/using-signalr-with-elasticache-fails",
         "title":"Using SignalR with ElastiCache fails"
      }
   ],
   "has_more":true,
   "quota_max":300,
   "quota_remaining":234
}
```

which *does* contain the screenshotted question:

```
{  
     "tags":[  
        "c#",
        "asp.net",
        "asp.net-mvc",
        "signalr"
     ],
     "owner":{  
        "reputation":8,
        "user_id":899974,
        "user_type":"registered",
        "profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/77be3b28cd3567ffa632d75aba0a2090?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "display_name":"ishahrier",
        "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/899974/ishahrier"
     },
     "is_answered":false,
     "view_count":397,
     "answer_count":0,
     "score":1,
     "last_activity_date":1414669608,
     "creation_date":1404240425,
     "last_edit_date":1414669608,
     "question_id":24517253,
     "link":"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517253/signalr-authentication",
     "title":"SignalR authentication"
  },
```

Comment: sorry i have edited the question as there were some changes in the second part, i should have done it earlier. the problem is in order of questions. the two questions have their positions swapped in json results as shown in the snapshots: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Awkl8.png & http://i.stack.imgur.com/ppLB7.png